# Reading embedded data into Qualtrics in a generalized way

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I have a set of embedded variables, q1_ans, q2_ans, q3_ans, ....

In one of my questions, I would like to read in all these vars one at a time as part of a loop:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  let ans_q = "e://Field/q" + i + "_ans"
  let ans = "${" + ans_q+ "}";﻿
  console.log(ans);
}
});
```

However, this is not reading in the embedded data values.﻿ How can I read in my embedded variables in a JS loop?

Answer (score 1):

Embedded data fields are resolved on the server before the page is sent to the browser, so  you can't dynamically build and resolve the pipe strings for embedded data fields in JavaScript.

You could pipe all the strings into an array definition, then loop through the array.

Another alternative would be to use Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData() if it still works (no longer included in documentation).

Comment: I was able to use the the `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData()` method successfully! For posterity, how would I use the array method? I would start by piping all of the `ans_q ` to an array, and how would I read that in?